# Passing Array into SQL query in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am following the CS50 of Harvard and I don't want to use CS50 library that they use for lecture purposes, but I could not figure out how to make this code work. A little help would be greatly appreciated

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

# Configure app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Connect to database
db = sqlite3.connect("store.db",check_same_thread=False)

c = db.cursor()
# Configure sessions
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
    list =[dict(id=book[0], title=book[1]) for book in books.fetchall() ]
    return render_template("books.html", books=list)


@app.route("/cart", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def cart():

    # Ensure cart exists
    if "cart" not in session:
        session["cart"] = []

    # POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        id = request.form.get("id")
        if id:
            session["cart"].append(id)
        return redirect("/cart")

    # GET
   
    books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (?)", [session("cart")])
    list =[dict(id=book[0], title=book[1]) for book in books.fetchall()]
    return render_template("cart.html", books=list)
```

The error is at the books=db.execute... line.

```
Error is :
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 9 supplied
```

I pressed the cart button 9 times, it is incrementing. Tried other solutions, could not still figure out.

Comment: `list =[dict(id=book[0], title=book[1]) for book in books.fetchall() ]` Do not use `list` as a varaible name

Comment: changed the variable name, still getting error :

Comment: Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2020-12-19 21:31:29,942] ERROR in app: Exception on /cart [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  /....
    __call__ = lambda x, *a, **kw: x._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
TypeError: 'FileSystemSession' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (?)", [session("cart")])`

should be

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN ({','.join(['?'] * len(session['cart']))})"
books =  db.execute(query,session['cart'])))
```

Comment: books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (?)", (session["cart"],))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.